# How to alter a DateTime field when it is updated?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, triggers

Is there a database level function (trigger or something) that I can use to alter a DateTime field when new data is inserted? The issue is that a service I am integrating with happens to send out all of its times (in this case the time some info was received on their end) in GMT.

I need to automatically change this to reflect the time in the timezone the db server is in. For example, if they send me 2:34 PM, but I am in NYC, I would want it to be entered in the db as 9:34 AM. This would also have to account for differences in Daylight Savings between GMT and wherever the server is, which seems like a nightmare. Any suggestions?

Also, I am using SQL Server 2005 if that helps.

EDIT:

Let me clarify one thing. The dates going into this column are retrieved in batches every so often (5, 10, 15 minutes), so I think the only way to go is to alter the time once it has been received, not to add a TimeModified field or something. Is that even feasible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could create

- a **default value** for the `DateTime` which gets set when you insert a new record

  ```
  CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ( ........,
    LastModifiedOn DATETIME 
        CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_LastModifiedOn DEFAULT (GETDATE())
  )
  ```
- a **AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER** which sets the `DateTime` field to the new value whenever you've updated your row

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate
  ON dbo.YourTable
  AFTER UPDATE 
  AS BEGIN
     UPDATE dbo.YourTable
     SET LastModifiedOn = GETDATE()
     FROM INSERTED i
     WHERE i.Table1ID = YourTable.Table1ID
  END
  ```

With the default value and the trigger, your datetime field `LastModifiedOn` should always be up to date and showing the last modification date/time.

Marc

Comment: Good suggestion, but please see the edit to my original post.

Comment: @marc_s Hope, trigger will update the DateTime in server location Date time format. Let's say if I want this to be in UTC, will it take care?

Comment: @RJN: use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` to get UTC time

Answer (score 1):

Another option here would be to use a calendar table where you map a UTC date and time to the local date and time value.

Disadvantages here are a loss in some of the granularity.  If seconds are important I would not implement this; you can look at the size of the calendar record and compare it to the size of storing a datetime for every record in your transactional table.  Obviously the smaller the volume the less beneficial this solution will be.  Also, if you don't build in automatic and unattended repopulating future records in the solution the table will "run out" of records, and you will have left a time bomb for whoever comes in after you (maybe yourself too).

Advantages though are that you will be able to perform any queries on this table much more quickly (because it is an integer).  Also if you ever decide that your NYC server needs to move to Sacramento, you can update the "`localDateTime`" and leave the UTC time in tact.

Table structure (granularity will be up to your needs):

```
ID int      
utc_month int  
utc_day int  
utc_year int  
utc_hour int  
utc_minute int  
local_month int  
local_day int  
local_year int  
local_hour int  
local_minute int
```

Yet **another** option (again depending on volume) is to deploy a managed assembly.
(see this site for instructions, you do have to make a server configuration change. [How to implement a managed udf or sp](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/10918_3399881_1/Implement-User-defined-Functions-in-SQL-Server-2005-with-Managed-Code.htm))

---

Here is the C# that I put in my `udf`

```
public static SqlDateTime udf_ConvertUTCDateTime(SqlDateTime utcDateTime)  
{  
    DateTime dt = utcDateTime.Value;  
    utcDateTime = dt.ToLocalTime();  
    return utcDateTime;  
}
```

The following code will return you the converted UTC datetime.  Just use that value in your insert or trigger.

```
Declare @D datetime
set @D = GetUTCDate()

select @D

select dbo.udf_ConvertUTCDateTime(@D)
```

Comment: With the new comment posted it sounds like converting the datetime would be easiest to implement in a managed udf.  This could be done in a trigger on insert or simply specified by converting the utc to local datetime in the insert statement.  This udf uses the utc offset of the local machine.  This is contingent on CLR being enabled for the SQL instance of course.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field of the type Timestamp - that will get updated whenever any data is modified in that row.  Alas, it's literally a relative timestamp, so it can only be used for versioning.  More information can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm not yet sure whether the field is updated on my side as soon as the service I'm working with updates it on theirs. If they send the received time immediately, this would work; otherwise I would have to convert the actual DateTime they send.

Answer (score 0):

following example should do the job. Add ModifiedOn or similar DateTime field to your db table.

```
insert into foo (field1, field2, ...., ModifiedOn)
values (value1, value2,...., GetDate())
```

or for update

```
update Foo
set field1 = value1,
    field2 = value2,
    .
    .
    .
    .,

    ModifiedOn = GetDate()
Where ....
```